# ggplot: No legend when using scale_fill_brewer with geom_contour_filled

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've plotted a specific set of meteorological data using ggplot as described in the R code below.   However, when I use scale_fill_brewer to specific the fill color, a legend does not appear.

What changes are necessary for the legend to appear?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)


qurl <- "https://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/met/ag/strat/produkte/qbo/singapore.dat"

sing <- read_table(qurl, skip=4)

# the data file adds a 100mb data row starting in 1997 increasing the number of rows per year from 
# 14 to 15.   So, one calcuation must be applied to rnum <140 and a different to rnum >140.

sing2 <- sing %>% separate(1,into=c('hpa','JAN'),sep='\\s+') %>%  drop_na() %>% 
  subset(hpa != 'hPa') %>%  
  mutate(rnum = row_number(),
         hpa=as.integer(hpa)) %>% 
  mutate(year = case_when(rnum <=140 ~ 1987 + floor(rnum/14),  # the last year with 14 rows of data
                          rnum >=141 ~ 1987 + floor(rnum+10/15))) %>%  # the first year with 15 rows of data
  relocate(year, .before='hpa') %>% arrange(year,hpa) %>%  
  pivot_longer(cols=3:14, names_to='month',values_to='qbo') %>%  
  mutate(date=ymd(paste0(year,'-',month,'-15')),
         hpa=as.integer(hpa),
         qbo=as.numeric(qbo))

sing2 <- sing %>% separate(1,into=c('hpa','JAN'),sep='\\s+') %>%  drop_na() %>% 
         subset(hpa != 'hPa') %>%  
         mutate(year=1987+floor(row_number()/15),
                hpa=as.integer(hpa)) %>%  
         relocate(year, .before='hpa') %>% arrange(year,hpa) %>%  
         pivot_longer(cols=2:13, names_to='month',values_to='qbo') %>%  
         mutate(date=ymd(paste0(year,'-',month,'-15')),
                hpa=as.integer(hpa),
                qbo=as.numeric(qbo))
# End Data Massaging.   It's ready to be graphed
# A simple call to ggplot with geom_contour_filled generates a legend
sing2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=hpa)) + 
  geom_contour_filled(aes(z=qbo*0.1)) +
  scale_y_reverse()

# Adding scale_fill_brewer removes the legend. 
# Adding show.legend = TRUE to the geom_countour_filled options has no effect. 

limits = c(-1,1)*max(abs(sing2$qbo),na.rm=TRUE)
zCuts <-  round(seq(limits[1], limits[2], length.out = 11), digits=0)

sing2 %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(x=date,y=hpa, z = qbo*0.1),breaks=zCuts*0.1) +
  scale_y_reverse(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), date_breaks = '1 year', date_labels = '%Y') + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 5,type='div',breaks=zCuts) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'right',
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Please skip the "data massaging" sections and start with some reproducible code that is enough to generate a representative plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP, I don't have a direct answer for you, given that your example is not able to be replicated (unable to access the data you gave).  In place, I can give you a bit of advice on debugging, since it seems the issue is related to the `breaks=` argument of `scale_fill_brewer()`.  As you mention, you get a legend when using `geom_contour_filled()`, but not when you add the `scale_fill_brewer()` part.

Let me use the example from the [documentation for geom_contour_filled() to illustrate this behavior](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html), which utilizes the built-in dataset, `fathfuld`.

I'll add in your own `palette` and `type` choice, leaving out the `breaks` argument for example:

```
v <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density))
v + geom_contour_filled() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 5, type='div')
```

[image]

If you do the same thing, but add in a "nonsensical" breaks argument, you get the same plot, but without a legend (like you are seeing):

```
v + geom_contour_filled() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 5, type='div', breaks=1:4)
```

[image]

For me, this is good evidence that the issue in your code relates to the value for `breaks=` not being within the range expected.  Is this just a typo?  Note that `breaks=zCuts` in `scale_fill_brewer()`, yet `breaks=zCuts*0.1` in `geom_contour_filled()`.  This would put each value for your color scale to be 10 times outside the range of the breaks for the contours themselves.  I'd be willing to bet that this change to that `scale_fill_brewer()` line will do the trick:

```
# earlier plot code
... +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = 5,type='div',breaks=zCuts*0.1) +
... 
# remaining plot code
```

Comment: I move the *0.1 to the data massaging section, where it should have been in the first place.  Aligning the breaks and the with zCuts did not solve the problem.  However, removing the breaks option generates a plot with the legend, which I decided to use. 

Thanks for your help.